# ConcurrentSkipListSet using Comparator will not add new unique values

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I want a concurrent set of string values sorted by length longest -> shortest.

This is my code (JAVA 8):

```
private ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> sortedSourceTypeNames = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());
```

Here is the java 8 documentation:

```
    /**
     * Constructs a new, empty set that orders its elements according to
     * the specified comparator.
     *
     * @param comparator the comparator that will be used to order this set.
     *        If {@code null}, the {@linkplain Comparable natural
     *        ordering} of the elements will be used.
     */
    public ConcurrentSkipListSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        m = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<E,Object>(comparator);
    }
```

Now here is the weird thing:

1. add new value "some_str" -> ok
2. add new value "some_els" -> **not added**
3. add new value "some" -> ok

Debugging this phenomenon I saw that the ConcurrentSkipListSet is rejecting new unique strings that have the same length of an already existing string in the set.

And I was like Waaaattt?!?!?

This is an unexpected behavior which is not mentioned in any documentation.

Is this a bug in the JAVA ConcurrentSkipListSet implementation? or it's something I did?

**Edit:**

Thank u all for the quick response!

I just want to point out that this behavior is documented in the JAVA SortedSet interface (but not in the ConcurrentSkipListSet):

```
* <p>Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an
 * explicit comparator is provided) must be <i>consistent with equals</i> if
 * the sorted set is to correctly implement the <tt>Set</tt> interface.  (See
 * the <tt>Comparable</tt> interface or <tt>Comparator</tt> interface for a
 * precise definition of <i>consistent with equals</i>.)  This is so because
 * the <tt>Set</tt> interface is defined in terms of the <tt>equals</tt>
 * operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its
 * <tt>compareTo</tt> (or <tt>compare</tt>) method, so two elements that are
 * deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set,
 * equal.  The behavior of a sorted set <i>is</i> well-defined even if its
 * ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general
 * contract of the <tt>Set</tt> interface.
```

Comment: Well, the comparator you provided in the constructor are comparing lengths. The set will use that comparator to determine if two elements are equal.

Comment: A Set, any Set, is a collection rejecting duplicates. By definition. Your comparator says that two strings are equal when they have the same length. So the secon string is rejected.

Comment: How is that a bug? You are saying that you want unique elements *by lenght*

Comment: yes but the comparator should just order the set, no?

Comment: No. Read the documentation of SortedSet (that CSLSet implements): *Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface. [...] This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted set performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted set, equal.*

Comment: if I create new ConcurrentSkipListSet it will function as a set and order the elements by their natural ordering. so I expected when given a custom comparator it will just use it to order by and not to check if equal

Comment: Your comparator returns true whenever `str1.length() == str2.length()`. It doesn't matter what str1 and str2 contains.

Comment: The Javadoc on this seems wrong or at least seriously misleading. The comments for `add` say that "More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that e.equals(e2).". That's not strictly correct. Forcing the user to dig through the javadocs for the highest parent of the interface it implements to learn about the implicit contract between `equals` and `compareTo` seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparator you have provider returns that strings of the same length are equal, thus duplicates which are ignored.

The default use of `ConcurrentSkipListSet` is like

```
Set<String> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(
        Comparator.comparing(s -> s));
```

or

```
Set<String> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(
        Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

when you set the Comparator, you replace the default comparator and it doesn't default back to the default behaviour if your comparator states two objects are equal.

One way around this is to sort by length and then by content on equal length.

```
Set<String> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(
        Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed()
        .thenComparing(s -> s));

set.add("aa");
set.add("bb");
set.add("aaa");
set.add("ccc");
System.out.println(set);
```

prints

```
[aaa, ccc, aa, bb]
```

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).reversed() .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder())`, which might be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @Holger `naturalOrder` might be clearer unless you know what `s -> s` means. I suspect the `s -> s` would be specific to String (monomorphic) whereas `naturalOrder` might be polymorphic depending on whether you use it for other types.

Comment: Keep in mind that `.thenComparing(s->s)` is just a shorthand for `.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(s->s))`, so you’re combining the monomorphic `s->s` function with the polymorphic delegating comparator returned by `Comparator.comparing(Function)` (that’s especially true when using `Comparator.comparing(Function) .thenComparing(Function)`). Both variants, `.thenComparing(naturalOrder())` and `.thenComparing(s->s)` end up at a polymorphic comparator calling `Comparable.compareTo`, but the latter will also evaluate the provided identity function on each element before invoking `compareTo`.